# Which TomcatCometSupport class to use in Tomcat 7.0.52?

Tags: java, tomcat, comet, atmosphere

I am migrating tomcat 6.0.35 to 7.0.52 and noticed following warning message in catalina.out.

```
2014-03-03 17:35:05,655  WARN DefaultAsyncSupportResolver - Found multiple containers, please specify which one to use: org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7CometSupport, org.atmosphere.container.TomcatCometSupport,  until you do, Atmosphere will use:class org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7CometSupport
```

It appears that atmosphere-runtime-2.0.0.RC2.jar file contains TomcatCometSupport and Tomcat7CometSupport.  Currently, Tomcat7.0.52 display a warning message and using Tomcat7CometSupport. Is it ok to ignore the warning message? How can I configure tomcat container class? Which one is recommended to use?

[TomcatCometSupport](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.atmosphere/atmosphere-runtime/2.0.0/org/atmosphere/container/TomcatCometSupport.java)

[Tomcat7CometSupport](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.atmosphere/atmosphere-runtime/2.0.0/org/atmosphere/container/Tomcat7CometSupport.java)

I am using gwt-atmosphere in my web application.

Look like cometsupport can be configured with o.a.cpr.asyncSupport init params http://async-io.org/config_table.html ,https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Forcing-Atmosphere-AsyncSupport